# PostgreSQL dumping JSONB column into a line JSON file

Tags: json, postgresql

I understand I can always go through a driver in some scripting language like `Python`. But I am trying to make things simple here.

In a `PostgreSQL` database, I have a table that saves a JSONB column of raw tweets from Twitter. I have attempted to dump the column into a line JSON file by

```
psql -U UUU -h HHH -c "COPY rawtwts(tweet) TO stdout CSV QUOTE E'\b' NULL AS ''" | gzip > dump.json.gz
```

And then I realize I need to do a bunch of `tr -d` and `sed` to trim escaping and weird characters before parsing the line JSON tweet file, which is really counter-productive.

`CSV QUOTE E'\b'` allows me to filter the escapes by `tr -d '\010'`. Otherwise in text mode the JSON will contain things like:

```
, "source": "<a href=\\"https://mobile.twitter.com\\" rel=\\"nofollow\\">Twitter Web App</a>"
```

Any suggestions for a simpler way?

Comment: what if you dump your data without `copy` command, but dump it using `psql`: 
`\t
\a
\o file.json
SELECT row_to_json(r) FROM rawtwts AS r; `